# iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x3f0707 error on boot with Ubuntu 20.04 after entering BIOS

Tags: boot, 20.04, bios

I tried to enable BIOS settings for Wake-on-LAN on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. After I came out of my BIOS settings Ubuntu is not booting. I keep getting the "iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x3f0707" error or a blinking cursor with blank screen. I tried to revert the BIOS settings to default but that did not solve the problem either.

Any suggestions would be of great help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. A quick search on Google shows this error is documented. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203593 It looks like you  have changed something else in the BIOS or have done something to the OS. Corrupted it in some way.