# Ubuntu 22.04 does not boot after update including in recovery mode (network) and with older kernel

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04, bios, iwlwifi

I recently updated my packages on Ubuntu 22.04 via software update which includes a bunch of Ubuntu-labeled stuff. Since then, after I restarted my computer, Ubuntu does not boot anymore. During booting, I get a bunch of error messages (shown below) and then a blinking cursor. I tried using the old kernel but the same thing happens.

I initially thought this could be related to a recent BIOS update although I had restarted my computer after the upgrade and Ubuntu didn’t have an issues booting. Still I logged into Windows and downloaded the older BIOS firmware installation file from Dell website and downgraded my BIOS version from 1.12 to 1.11 (which was released in March). This has not resolved the boot issue either.

Does anyone have an idea what I should do to resolve this?

[image]

I tried fixing this issue by unchecking the following settings in BIOS settings. This removed the error messages that start with ‘Iwlwifi’ but the other errors stay there, the blinking cursor shows up again and Ubuntu does not boot. Wake on LAN is also disabled by default in BIOS settings which seems to have caused a similar issue ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398132/iwlwifi-00000600-0-unhandled-alg-0x3f0707-error-on-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04-af))

[image]

I think the problem has something to do with my network card because when I enter the recovery mode and want to boot Ubuntu with network enabled, I get the following error message and Ubuntu does not boot. I’m really confused and shocked and not sure what to do now.

[image]
I’m not sure if this is relevant but I also did autoremove on Terminal after I updated the software to remove packages that Ubuntu thought are not being used

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem had nothing to do with BIOS upgrade or the errors for network hardware and the OS was booted fine. The main issue was the GUI could not load and that's why I was getting the blinking cursor. All I had to do was to uninstall the Intel proprietary graphics driver and everything works fine now. I installed the driver a few months ago not knowing that it's not a good idea to do it since my laptop has a discrete graphics card. Here's how I fixed the issue:

- When the blinking cursor showed up I pressed CTRL + ALT + F2 to enter tty.
- Then I typed my username and then my passsword and logged in
- I did `dpkg --get-selections | grep i915` to get the package name for the Intel integrated driver
- I copied the output of that which was something like `intel-dkm...` and did `sudo apt-get purge THAT_NAME`
- Reboot

Comment: Thank you, Amir. My Dell 5490 with Ubuntu 22.04 would not return from a lock screen or suspend. I searched installed packaged for i915 and found xserver-xorg-video-intel. Removing xserver-xorg-video-intel and rebooting now allows my Dell 5490 to return from locked screen and from suspend. Previously, I had to reboot to get the desktop back. The description for this driver says it should not be used on most systems created after about 2007. Kind of curious why it is automatically installed.